# Android CursorAdapter save item state

Tags: android, cursor, android-adapter, android-cursoradapter

I have a layout with some basic info and heart symbol. When user press on heart symbol heart should change its color (become red from grey)and then I update my database (basically insert id of list item to my database). When I press on heart symbol everything is working fine (heart color changes and new record to my database is inserted) but when I scroll down and then back to the same position (where I previously pressed on heart icon) heart icon still colored in gray.

Here's my code

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_info_layout, parent, false);
    }

     @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        final ImageView heartImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.heart);
        int typeId = cursor.getInt(1);

        if(typeId == 0){
            heartImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.redHeart);
        } else {
            heartImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.greyHeart);
        }

        heartImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseUpdater.getInstance(myContext).update(id);
               // notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

as you can see heart color depends on my database record

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is expected.  Cursors are immutable by design which means any changes made to the DB *after* the cursor is retrieved won't be in that cursor.  There are a few simple choices:

1. Re-query the database for an updated cursor
2. Persist a separate list for that heart state (not a cursor)
3. Use a List<> instead of a cursor

My recommendation would be to use the 3rd option because it avoids other complications (scroll position, maintenance, etc.) as well as database access issues.